# Probability of having a path connecting clusters of random graphs

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, graph-theory, random-graphs

Construct a graph $H$ with $3n$ nodes in this way:

- Create three $G(n, p)$ graphs on a line, each with $p{n \choose 2}$ many edges within each cluster.
- For any node-pair in the neighboring clustering, add edges between them with probability $q$. Hence we'd end up with $qn^2$ many nodes collecting the nodes of the neighboring clusters.

**Question:** what is the probability that we'd have at least a path connecting the left-most cluster to the right-most cluster, in terms of $p$, $q$, and $n$.

[image]

Comment: So you need each subgraph being a connected graph, and there exist at least one edge connecting subgraph 1 to subgraph 2, and subgraph 2 to subgraph 3?

Comment: Your second bullet point makes it unclear whether you're creating edges independently with probabilities $p$ and $q$, respectively, or selecting random subsets of $p\binom n2$ and $qn^2$ edges, respectively. Are you only interested in asymptotic results where this might not matter?

Comment: @BGM yup, correct.

Comment: @joriki the former is correct:  creating edges independently with probabilities $p$ and $q$